# Quiz: Determine first principal component from data-plots

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, pca

We see four data plots. The goal: How does the first principal component look for each plot a-d. For plot d, it is true that both clusters have same number of datapoints.

First principal component indicates axis with highest variance. I think first dataset (a) is diagonal line. I think (b) has infinite number, because every diameter of circle has highest variance. I think (c) again like (a). And I would say also (d) is same, because small cluster has little variance only. What does the community think?[image]

Comment: Because (b) consists of a finite data set, it is not perfectly circularly symmetric: it will still have distinct principal directions with slightly different eigenvalues.  They will be very difficult to determine from visual inspection of the plot.  The subtlest situation is (d).  Its first principal component should point approximately left to right (between the two cluster centers near $(-1,0)$ and $(2,0)$), because there is much more variance due to the separation of the point clouds than there is within the clouds collectively. The ratio of the squared eigenvalues is very close to $8:1$.

Comment: wow very good answer. I think too that b) has not everywhere some distribution of points, but seems very vague. You see that d) eigenvector is not on y = x axis. But why the code below shows eigenvector on this axis? Thanks you whuber for your insight